# WebRequest set timeout on incomplete slow response

Tags: timeout, system.net.httpwebrequest

I know [`WebRequest.Timeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) sets the timeout for the request, but that seems to only be enforced until the server begins responding.

What should I do if I want to timeout when the server sends some data then stops responding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `...Async` versions of the read calls, and call [`Task.Wait(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644(v=vs.110).aspx) with the timeout:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream )) {
    var task = reader.ReadLineAsync();
    if (!task.Wait(1000)) {
        throw new Exception("Timed out after 1 sec.");
    }
    string line = task.Result;
    // etc....
}
```